# What are the Pointers before using parentheses and casting func means in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Studying `C++` with some sources I often came to see this, I'm a bit confused about this part of example source code (game server, on packet delete part) :

```
auto opcode = **reinterpret_cast<uint16_t**>((static_cast<char*>(packet) + 0x1050));
auto ptr = (char*)(*(void**)(static_cast<char*>(packet) + 0x1034));
uint16_t raw = *(const uint16_t*)ptr, packetSize = raw & 0x7FFF;
```

Image (marked as red squares) :

[image]

- What do the pointers in front of parentheses means ? `(*(void**)`, `*(const uint16_t*)`
- What do the double pointers in front of casting functions ? `**reinterpret_cast<uint16_t**>`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and abandon all those stars. And casts.

Comment: Haha :) I'm not a skilled C++ developer. I have just wondered. I did research on Google but I did not anythink find abaut it. :)

Comment: It's dereferencing a pointer. But this code is a mish-mash of styles (and looks really suspicious)

Comment: Don't go astray in an unreadable, suspicious and dangerous labyrinths.

Comment: Since you're a beginner, don't dig into what this code means. It's horrible stuff. It will only give you a headache.

Comment: dude where did you find this stuff. At first I thought it was some machine generated code but that last line just looks like intentionally misleading code. Why would someone use the comma operator where a semicolon would do the same.

Comment: Here is a list of some [fine C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. But I do not understand why question got -rep points. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not pointer - it is operator dereferencing pointer.

you can always split this expression into smaller parts to analyze it.

```
x = **reinterpret_cast<uint16_t**>(something)
```

could be read as

```
temp1 = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t**>(something); //temp1 is uint16_t**
temp2 = *temp1; // dereference pointer temp1 - got uint16_t*
x = *temp2; //well x is uint16_t to which temp2 was pointing to...
```

you can do the same for all other stars you have marked

Answer (score 1):

The asterix * mean dereferencing. Dereferencing mean, use the pointer as an address and get the content a this address. How the content will be interpreted depends on further parts of the type info

After applying `reinterpret_cast<uint16_t**>` you have a pointer to a pointer of `uint16_t`. When dereferencing twice you get an `uint16_t`.

`*(void**)`: this means, you interpret the right, not mentioned side as a pointer to a pointer of `void`. By dereferencing once, you got a pointer of `void`.

`*(const uint16_t*)`: this means, you interpret the right, not mentioned side as an pointer a `const uint16_t`. By  dereferencing once, you got that `const uint16_t`.